# Why React-Native Couldn't start project on Android connection with Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

Couldn't start project on Android.

Error : No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically.

Please connect a device or create an emulator (https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator).

Then follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

Comment: Could you give us information about how did you install android studio ? Thank you

Answer (score 20):

In order to run your `React Native` application, you first need to run an emulator seperately. It won't start an emulator automatically like a native `Android Studio` build.

- Create an `AVD` using [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createavd) tutorial.
- Note down your `AVD` name, if you are gonna run it without `Android Studio`.
- Run below code in a `Command Prompt` window to start emulator without `Android Studio`. Assuming that you have installed your `SDK` in default location, otherwise change it to your location.

  ```
  cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
  emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30
  ```
- **Pixel_2_API_30** is the name of `AVD` so change it to yours.

**For Mac** *(Followed [this](https://medium.com/@kobby.fletcher/launch-android-emulator-from-mac-terminal-3cbb087d408b) article)*

Assuming your Android SDK was installed to the default location…

- Export the emulator to your PATH.

  `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/' >>  ~/.bash_profile`
- Reload your terminal from source.

  `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now you can show all the emulators you’ve already created.

  `emulator -list-avds`
- You can run any of them by typing emulator and then @.
  So if one of your devices is called 'MyPixelDevice', you’ll run it like so

  `emulator @MyPixelDevice`

Once your emulator is running then you can run your `React Native` build as stated in [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) setup guide.

Comment: thank's  for your complete amswer. but my cpu doesn't support VT technology and because of this problem I can't  Create an AVD.

Comment: my cpu dosen't support  VT  and I should change it.  this my cpu:                           model number  : 37
model name : Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        P6200  @ 2.13GHz                     Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) : No

Comment: how do i start the emulator on mac?

Comment: @ObaApi I edited my answer with mac information. Also linked the original article for that so you can surf that too if you need.

Comment: for Windows these commands should look like this:

cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

.\emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30

Comment: @Vadym I don't think my answer is wrong here. You just wrote the same command and called the `emulator` method.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar it wouldn't work the way you presented, but using .\emulator successfully executed

Comment: @Vadym did you even try the command before commenting that? Because I am using it currently the way I answered. I urge you to at least check before claiming a code doesn't work.

Comment: @ZankrutParmar, yes I have tried that, however different environment and OS configuration vary could have caused this. It didn't work for me, hence the comment.